# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. clicking button in webpage via powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to click a button within a synology nas webpage environment.
Sadly the `$link=$ie.Document.getElementByID('ext-gen258') $linck.click()`

doesn't work as the element id constantly changes when you reload the page.

The element im trying to open:

```
<div class="item-wrap" id="ext-gen1413" role="button" aria-labelledby="controlpanel:leaf_security" cate="tree:node_connection" fn="SYNO.SDS.AdminCenter.Security.Main">
    <div class="icon-image syno-app-admin-center-icon-image" style='background-image: url("webman/modules/AdminCenter/images/default/1x/home_icons/security.png?v=25426-s2");'></div>
    <div class="text" id="controlpanel:leaf_security">Beveiliging</div>
</div>
```

I also tried the following code:

```
$button = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("div") | 
          Where-Object {$_.value -eq "controlpanel:leaf_security"}

$button.click()
```

But then the code wont resume and get stuck.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$button = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("div") | Where-Object {$_.value -eq "controlpanel:leaf_security"}` is probably returning more than one result.

Comment: how am i to specify that line then? is there a way to get the code to only look at this variable? `aria-labelledby="controlpanel:leaf_security" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$doc = $ie.document

# commit the button
$commit = $doc.getElementById("controlpanel:leaf_security")
if ($commit) { $commit.click() }
```

this code works... dont know why tho would love to have a explanation.